# What happen if in div tag of php, class and id both will write?

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I found the code in my index.php file of joomla 2.5 beez2 theme which is write like below. Please help me out with this code. because I am not able to understand clearly that what this code will include actually... class or id?

```
<div class="left1 <?php if ($showRightColumn==NULL){ echo 'leftbigger';} ?>" id="nav">
```

Comment: Your question is not clear but the code you posted is just adding a class if something is null

Comment: I rolled back the last edit to the question. Text is superior to pictures of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's adding a second `class` to the `div`

So, in CSS you can access the `div` by either class, or both classes.

HTML:

```
<div class="first second">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.first{

}

.second{

}

.first.second{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both. Start tags are allowed to have multiple attributes on them.

The output will, depending on the resolution of the `if`, be either of:

```
<div class="left1 " id="nav">
<div class="left1 leftbigger" id="nav">
```